# Assign null value to a decimal field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2014

I want to assign `null value` in a field in *SQL 2014* which has a data type, `decimal`. I tried to use theses codes but I didn't get the way I wanted *(providing that other fieldnames and values are present.)*

```
query = "INSERT INTO DBNAME.TLTRPRGP(DECIMALVAL) VALUES(@DECIMALVAL)"
params = New String() {"BLGSCD"}
values = New String() {Nothing}

SaveUpdateDelete(query, params, values)


query = "INSERT INTO DBNAME.TLTRPRGP(DECIMALVAL) VALUES(@DECIMALVAL)"
params = New String() {"BLGSCD"}
values = New String() {DbNull.Value}

SaveUpdateDelete(query, params, values)


query = "INSERT INTO DBNAME.TLTRPRGP(DECIMALVAL) VALUES(@DECIMALVAL)"
params = New String() {"BLGSCD"}
values = New String() {VbNull}

SaveUpdateDelete(query, params, values)


Private Sub SaveUpdateDelete(ByVal sql As String, ByVal parameters() As String, ByVal Values() As String)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
    End If
    con.Open()

    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    command = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

    For i = 0 To parameters.Count - 1
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & parameters(i).ToString, Values(i))
    Next
    command.CommandText = sql
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

The first code `returns 0`. The second returns *syntax error* saying `"Value System.DbNull.Value cannot be converted to String"`. The third code `returns 1`. All these codes failed to return the right value which is suppose to be `NULL` or `EMPTY`. What else is there to try?

Comment: what happens inside `SaveUpdateDelete`? how you handle the input of that function? wild guess: values should not be strings but objects.

Comment: @Paolo you're right! Thanks a lot. It helped. You can put your comment as an answer. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is with the datatype of the values: you constrain it to be a string but there are values that cannot be converted to strings (eg: `DBNull.Value`).

the solution is to use the generic `object` as the datatype for the parameters passed to the function `SaveUpdateDelete`.